# Infinite loop, can't find out why

Tags: php, algorithm, infinite-loop

Consider the following problem: http://adventofcode.com/day/7

I have the following code:

```
<?php

function log_not($intArg) {
    $strArr = str_split(str_pad(decbin($intArg), 16, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT));

    for ($i = 0; $i < 16; $i++) { $strArr[$i] = ($strArr[$i] == "0") ? "1" : "0"; }

    return (bindec(implode($strArr)));
}

function traverseTree($tree, $startNode) {
    sleep(1);
    echo ($startNode."\n");

    if (is_numeric($startNode)) {
        return (int)$startNode;
    } else {        
        $thisNode = $tree[$startNode];

        if (is_array($thisNode)) {
            print_r($thisNode);
            echo ("\n");

            switch ($thisNode[0]) {

                case "NOT": 
                    return log_not(traverseTree($tree, $thisNode[1])); 
                    break;

                case "AND":
                    return ((int)traverseTree($tree, $thisNode[1]) & (int)traverseTree($tree, $thisNode[2])); 
                    break;

                case "OR":
                    return ((int)traverseTree($tree, $thisNode[1]) | (int)traverseTree($tree, $thisNode[2])); 
                    break;

                case "RSHIFT":
                    return ((int)traverseTree($tree, $thisNode[1]) >> (int)($thisNode[2])); 
                    break;

                case "LSHIFT":
                    return ((int)traverseTree($tree, $thisNode[1]) << (int)($thisNode[2])); 
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            echo ($thisNode."\n\n");
            if (is_numeric($thisNode)) {
                //echo ("Number\n");
                return $thisNode;
            } else {
                //echo ("String\n");
                return (int)traverseTree($tree, $tree[$startNode]);
            }
        }
    }
}

$logicTree = [];
$myfile = fopen("day7_input - kopia.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");

while(!feof($myfile)) {
    $line = trim(fgets($myfile));
    $lineArr = explode(" ", $line);

    if (count($lineArr) == 3) {
        $logicTree[$lineArr[2]] = $lineArr[0];
    } elseif (count($lineArr) == 4) {
        $logicTree[$lineArr[3]] = [$lineArr[0], $lineArr[1]];
    } else {
        $logicTree[$lineArr[4]] = [$lineArr[1], $lineArr[0], $lineArr[2]];
    }
}

fclose($myfile);

//print_r($logicTree);

echo (traverseTree($logicTree, "a"));

?>
```

For some reason, I get an infinite loop in the `traverseTree()`-function. I don't know why, and I have rewritten the function a lot of times. The help-functions for logical bitwise operations are because I thought that the normal operators might be faulty. Can anyone see why?

My input can be found at http://pub.bluie.se/day7_input.txt

Either `$startnode` is a number (or a string formatted as a number) in which case `is_numeric` should evaluate that according to the documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php). If it is a number, the function should return that number.

If it is not a number, it is a string, which in it's case is a key in `$tree`. For example, if `$startnode` is `x`, it is a key to `$tree` which can have the following example values:

```
x => 123        should return 123
x => y          should call traverseTree($tree, "y")
x => ["NOT", "y"]   should call log_not(traverseTree($tree, "y"))
x => ["NOT", "1"]   should call log_not(traverseTree($tree, "1"))
x => ["AND", "y", "z"]  should call (traverseTree($tree, "y") & traverseTree($tree, "z"))
x => ["AND", "1", "z"]  should call (traverseTree($tree, "1") & traverseTree($tree, "z"))
x => ["AND", "y", "1"]  should call (traverseTree($tree, "y") & traverseTree($tree, "1"))
x => ["OR", "y", "z"]   should call (traverseTree($tree, "y") | traverseTree($tree, "z"))
x => ["OR", "1", "z"]   should call (traverseTree($tree, "1") | traverseTree($tree, "z"))
x => ["OR", "y", "1"]   should call (traverseTree($tree, "y") | traverseTree($tree, "1"))
x => ["LSHIFT", "y", 1] should call (traverseTree($tree, "y") << 1)
x => ["LSHIFT", "1", 1] should call (traverseTree($tree, "1") << 1)
x => ["RSHIFT", "y", 1] should call (traverseTree($tree, "y") >> 1)
x => ["RSHIFT", "1", 1] should call (traverseTree($tree, "1") >> 1)
```

Comment: Step through in a debugger?

Comment: @EricJ. I never used a proper debugger before so I don't really know where to start. I tried do debug it step by step as far as I could, but since the recursions are piling up and it's a binary tree, it is really hard to follow. I couldn't find any errors as far as I went.

Comment: @RyanVincent Sounds very logic, and I already did this before so I can give you the answers. 1) The input file has 339 lines (each line is instruction) and `count($logicTree)` gives 339. I even manually checked that the elements were correct from the lines. 2) `var_dump` on `$thisNode` gives different values each time. 3) I added a counter to count the depth of the tree, and it works as intended. I also followed the counter somewhat forwards and the backwards at a leaf, and the recursions also seems to be working as intended.

Comment: @BluePrint: A debugger is one of the most important and valuable programming tools.  There are plenty of tutorials about using a debugger with PHP available on the net. Solid debugging support came a bit late to PHP compared to other languages, so you will see advice to use output and exits to trouble-shoot.  That's a very 1970's approach.  I strongly suggest you spend a little time learning to use a debugger.

Comment: @RyanVincent `die('i am here: '.__FILE__.__LINE__);` after the while-loop did stop there and gave the correct line. But! Creating a small test tree and running it gave different answer than dion it manually, so that might be the problem. I'll have to check that tomorrow, it's 2 am here in Sweden.

Comment: I don't think it is an infinite loop. it is a big tree, though, and you are traversing it back down everytime (e.g. `x -> y; a AND b -> x; 123 -> a; 42 -> b;`, you'll go through almost all lines every time.) try to memoize the results of your calls.